# How did my iPhone determine the location of Photos when off-line?

Tags: graphics, camera, geolocation

How did my iPhone determine the location of a Photo when the iPhone was offline and not connected to any wifi? It even determined the location exactly, even though there was no Network. How does this mechanism work?

Answer (score 3):

That's what [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) is for, which doesn't require data connectivity because, like any GPS receiver, it gets its position data directly from the GPS satellites.